# Amazon Product Advertising API: Get Product Detail URL from ASIN

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am using the [PHP Soap Library](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/4373) to connect to Amazon and retrieve product cover art from ASINs. That much I've accomplished, but according to the [Agreement](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_t=501&ref_=amb_link_83952631_8&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=&pf_rd_s=assoc-center-1&pf_rd_r=&pf_rd_i=assoc-api-detail-0) (at least as far as I can tell; IANAL), any info I get from the API must be linked to its respective Product Detail Page on the Amazon retail site. I've browsed through the [docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/), but for the life of me I can not figure out what method, etc. I need to use, short of constructing the URL manually (which is potentially unstable). Any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. This is the code I ended up using:

```
<?php
class AmazonMusicSearch extends AmazonECS {
    protected $asin;
    protected $detailPageUrl;
    protected $ecs;

    function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    function __construct() {
        $this->ecs = new parent(AZ_APP_ID, AZ_APP_SECRET, 'com', AZ_ASSOCIATE_TAG);
    }

    function searchByAsin($asin) {
        $search = $this->ecs->responseGroup('Small')->category('Music')->search($asin);

        $this->asin = $asin;

        if(isset($search['Items']['Item']['DetailPageURL'])) {
            $this->detailPageUrl = $search['Items']['Item']['DetailPageURL'];
        } elseif(isset($search['Items']['Item'][0]['DetailPageURL'])) {
            $this->detailPageUrl = $search['Items']['Item'][0]['DetailPageURL'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    function detailPageFromAsin($asin) {
        return $this->searchByAsin($asin)->detailPageUrl;
    }
}
?>
```